# How to store text inside elements in an ArrayList using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to store the text inside of the p elements which are inside a div in an ArrayList. The HTML is given below:

```
<div class="copy">
<p>First text</p>
<p>Second text</p>
<p>Third text</p>
</div>
```

I tried the following code but it concatenates all of the above and stores them as one instead of storing them separately:

```
Elements tips= doc.select("div.copy");
 for(Element tip: tips) {
  tipsArray.add(tip.text());
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
Elements tips= doc.select("div.copy > p");
for(Element tip: tips) {
   tipsArray.add(tip.html());
}
```

Comment: @BidhanA Glad to hear it!